# When is `finally` run in a Python generator?

Tags: python

I think I might misunderstand how the `finally` clause of a try/except/finally block works in Python, for generators.

In the following block of code, a generator starts a thread, and if the caller exits for any reason, the thread is cleaned up. That's the intention, at least.

However, I've noticed that in some strange situations, the `finally` block isn't run: If the caller raises and then catches their own exception, and assigns the exception object to a variable, the finally isn't run. I have no idea why this would be the case.

Here's the code.

```
import signal
from threading import Thread
import time


class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._stopped = False
    def run(self):
        while not self._stopped:
            time.sleep(0.2)
    def stop(self):
        self._stopped = True


class ThreadRunner:
    def start(self):
        self._my_thread = MyThread()
        self._my_thread.start()
    def end(self):
        self._my_thread.stop()
        self._my_thread.join()
        print('ThreadRunner end!')


def loop_forever():
    thread_runner = ThreadRunner()
    try:
        thread_runner.start()
        yield
    finally:
        print('loop_forever() is all done!')  # When does this line get run?
        thread_runner.end()


def listener():
    print('listener begin!')
    looper = loop_forever()
    next(looper)
    try:
        raise Exception()
    except Exception as e:
        es = e  # If you comment out this line (and replace it with `pass`), it doesn't hang
    print('listener... done!')


def main():
    def handle_exit(signum, *args): 
        raise Exception("SIGINT: EXITING")
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_exit)
    listener()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    print('This program has exited. Or has it?')
```

What you'll see if run this code is this:

[image: output until you press ctrl c]

Press CTRL+C to trigger a signal handler. That will raise an exception, which triggers the `finally` in question.

[image: an exception causes python to finally trigger a finally]

As I said above, if remove `es = e` (replace it with pass), for some reason, our code exits as expected.

```
def listener():
    print('listener begin!')
    looper = loop_forever()
    next(looper)
    try:
        raise Exception()
    except Exception as e:
        pass
        # es = e  # If you comment out this line (and replace it with `pass`), it doesn't hang
    print('listener... done!')
```

Also, if I re-write `listener()` to use a for loop instead of next(), our code exits as expected:

```
def listener():
    print('listener_using_next')
    for _ in loop_forever():
        try:
            raise Exception()
        except Exception as e:
            es = e
        print('listener_using_next... done!')
```

Edit: In response to one comment, I want to note that our code exits as expected even if you return early, interrupting the generator.

```
def listener():
    print('listener_using_next')
    for _ in loop_forever():
        try:
            raise Exception()
        except Exception as e:
            es = e
            return
        print('listener_using_next... done!')
```

Finally, if I invoke garbage collection after `main()` (with import `gc;gc.collect()`), our code exits *almost* as expected: The "This program has exited" line prints, followed by "loop_forever() is all done!"

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    print('This program has exited. Or has it?')
    import gc;gc.collect()
```

Can someone point to me to an explanation of how `finally:` works for generators? Ideally, in such a way that would help explain this strange behavior?

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't contain anything that would print "An iterator is all done!" Can you run the exact code you posted, and show the exact output produced?

Comment: Phew, good point. I think the code and output should all match now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`finally` in a generator is run under the same conditions as in any other code: when the execution of the `try` block finishes, as well as execution of any `except` block that got triggered, the `finally` runs. However, relative to most non-generator code, it is much easier in a generator for these conditions to just *not happen*.

When you suspend your generator in the middle of a `try`, the conditions for the `finally` to run have not occurred. If the generator just never resumes again, the conditions for the `finally` to run will never occur.

To try to bandage this a bit, when a generator is garbage collected, Python will throw a `GeneratorExit` exception into the generator. This *usually* causes the generator to run any pending `finally` blocks and finish up, but if the generator catches the exception and suspends again, or if the generator *doesn't* ever get garbage collected, `finally` blocks may not run.

---

In your test case, by saving the exception to the `es` variable, you create a reference cycle (through the exception object's stack trace) which keeps the generator alive. The `es = e` is necessary to create the reference cycle because Python sticks an implicit `del e` at the end of the `except` specifically to avoid a reference cycle. Python then just doesn't run garbage collection until the end of the program, at which point your generator finally gets cleaned up.

Note that there is no guarantee garbage collection will run, or that it will clean up everything it "should" clean up, and as you've seen, even if it does run, it doesn't have to run any time soon.

---

When you use a `for` loop instead of `next`, you're not leaving the generator suspended in the middle of the `try`. `for` runs the generator to completion, immediately and naturally running the `finally`.

Comment: I've wondered why Python has the implicit `del e` after an `except ... as e` block, and this Q&A explained it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the response! Almost everything you've said make sense, except the two things. First: If I add an `except` block to loop_forever() and print any exceptions encountered, I don't encounter a GeneratorExit (or any other exception). Second: See my question's edit above, but, even if you return early from within the for loop, the code exits as expected. Shouldn't it behave just like the large code block, which uses a next(), at that point?

Comment: @AdamEasterling: You didn't save the generator to a variable, so there's no reference cycle.

Comment: As for the `except`, you probably tried to catch `Exception`. `GeneratorExit` inherits directly from `BaseException` specifically so it won't be caught by `except` blocks that catch `Exception`. (This intent is somewhat undermined by the fact that the default for a blanket `except:` catches `BaseException`.) That, or maybe you added the `except` in the wrong place, or ran the generator to completion.

Comment: You've given a fantastic response! This explains my question as asked. Bringing this back to a real business problem: The key takeaway is to be super careful with using `finally:` within a generator. I'll start thinking of it as an anti-pattern.